# 'server too busy' error when using Microsoft Translator API from C#

Tags: c#, soap

I've got a program which we are going to use to generate rough translations of application strings using the **Microsoft Translator API** - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512435.aspx.

I've been receiving this error:

```
04/01/2011 19:21:36: ERROR: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: server too busy
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

Is anybody using this API? I'm concerned about it's reliability and thus it's usefulness to us for this project. We're accessing it from C# via SOAP.

Any help or comments from anyone who has used this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so much reliability, it throttles access.  The stated 'safe' usage is less than 50 requests per minutes and less than 1000 characters per requests.  Looks like there are licensing options to increase this.  The canonical answer [is here.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/microsofttranslator/thread/76f6bb3e-e34c-4056-9e64-4c8b26e618fe)